# Ruby on Rails third party plugins

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I was trying to develop rails app which supports third party plugins similar to Wordpress. Can somebody navigate me in which way I should look to develop it. Is there any gem which can help or any example?

Comment: what have you researched ?

Comment: I looked for rails tutorial how to develop plugins and engines, but in every case I need to change something in main code every time I want to add new plugin, I cannot find example anywhere on how to enable third party plugins to be added to my rails app